# How can I add decimal inputs and round off outputs?

Tags: python-3.x

I have been working on this calculator and have been trying to modify it so that it can take in user inputs that contain decimals and if the output were to have a decimal in it, to round it to the nearest whole number but I am not sure exactly where I should input the code. I have tried using the round() function but I end up getting a syntax error when I put it towards the bottom. Here is what I have so far.

```
def add(x, y ):
    return x + y
def subtract(x, y ):
    return x - y
def multiply (x, y ):
    return x * y
def divide(x, y ):
    return x / y


# while True:
cont = "y"
while cont.lower() == "y":
    print("Select operation\n1.Add\n2.Subtract\n3.Multiply\n4.Divide")

    choice = input("Enter choice(1/2/3/4):")
    num1 = int(input("Enter first number: "))
    num2 = int(input("Enter second number: "))

    if choice == '1' :
        print(num1, "+", num2, "=", add (num1, num2))

    elif choice == '2' :
        print(num1, "-", num2, "=", subtract(num1, num2))

    elif choice == '3' :
        print(num1, "*", num2, "=", multiply(num1, num2))

    elif choice == '4' :
        print(num1, "/", num2, "=", divide(num1, num2))
    cont = input("Continue?y/n:")
    if cont == "n":
        break
```

Comment: Do you want the answer rounded to the nearest integer, but still shown as a `float` or do you want to show the answer as an `int` type? E.g.: do you want `divide(4, 2)` to output `2.0` or `2`? Please also show where you're trying to `round` so we can help you track down your syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your code pretty much the way it is, but allow the user to optionally enter a floating point number that is rounded to the closest integer value then you only need to change this:

```
    num1 = int(input("Enter first number: "))
    num2 = int(input("Enter second number: "))
```

to this:

```
    num1 = round(float(input("Enter first number: ")))
    num2 = round(float(input("Enter second number: ")))
```